# PHP Array filtering

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, closures

I have more than 1k arrays of this format.

```
[0] => stdClass Object (
     [order_date] => 2017-11-23 
     [status] => Shipped
     [destination] => "Chicago" 
     [car_make] => YYY 
     [customer] => "Vic" ) 
[1] => stdClass Object (
         [order_date] => 2017-11-24 
         [status] => Received
         [destination] => "New York" 
         [car_make] => ZZZ
         [customer] => "Admin" ) 
[2] => stdClass Object (
         [order_date] => 2017-11-23 
         [status] => Shipped
         [destination] => "Detroit" 
         [car_make] => XXX 
         [customer] => "Vic" ) 
[3] => stdClass Object (
         [order_date] => 2017-11-13 
         [status] => Complete
         [destination] => "LA" 
         [car_make] => WWW 
         [customer] => "John" )
```

I would like to filter the whole data using multiple keys.
I have used [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in a closure and it works perfect filtering data based on one key only.

```
function cc_filter_car_data( $data )
{   
   return function( $key,$value ) use( $data )
   {
      return  array_filter( $data, function( $data_1 ) use( $key,$value )
      {
        return $data_1->$key === $value;
      });
   };
}
```

Example with the above `cc_filter_car_data()`  I can return all arrays where  `customer = Vic` (filters only one key).

But I want to return all arrays `where status=shipped` or `customer = Vic` or`car_make = ZZZ`. (multiple and different keys)
My question:
How can I solve this? Any help appreciated.
**Additional:**
In total each array has `13 keys` which can be filtered.
The idea is : the user can send the first filter as `car_make` then  filter the returned data based on `car_model` and so on

See a good jquery example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) 
I am doing the server side processing

Comment: You receive all the entries given a single filter, so would you be able to just get an array of filters and run `cc_filter_car_data()` for each filter specified?  Then it will only return values that satisfy each subsequent key, which should do what you're saying it needs to do.

Comment: I can get a single filter using ` cc_filter_car_data()` .The issue is I have 13 options to filter,these options can be null or have data  on any request

Comment: @cchoe1 Kindly see this jquery example https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html I need something of that sort

Comment: Based on your comment, it seems like you need to get a way to get the parameters in the first place.  Are you able to retrieve the inputs with AJAX and then querying when they hit an 'Update' button?  Then you should be able to simply receive the request and create an associative array like miknik created and you can use the filter name as a key, the filter value as the value and then match identical values.  You can remove the `break;` statement and add all the matches and then return the final array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array containing the k=>v pairs you want to match and use a nested foreach loop

```
$search = array();
$search['status'] = 'shipped';
$search['customer'] = 'Vic';
$search['car_make'] = 'ZZZ';
$returnArray = array();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    foreach ($search as $k=>$v) {
        if ($d->$k === $v) {
        $returnArray[] = $d;
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($returnArray);
```